# Logs generated using ESAPI logger

Tags: logging, log4j, esapi

I am using ESAPI logger in my application.
Logger logger= ESAPI.getLogger(ABC.class)

In class ABC.java, we are using INFO level to print logs. By definition we know, Info accepts:

**Two args:** 
info(Logger.EventType type, java.lang.String message)

**Three args:**
info(Logger.EventType type, java.lang.String message, java.lang.Throwable throwable)

I have provided two arguments in my application:
logger.info(EVENT_TYPE,msg);

Logs are generating in the format:

**[EVENT SUCCESS Anonymus:null@unknown-> /com.sample.package.ABC][msg]**

I want logs in this format:

**[EVENT SUCCESS][msg]**

Please tell me how can I remove the extra details which are getting printed because of EVENT_TYPE argument.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible without rewriting that part of the library.  There's currently no configuration controls for that.

Submit a PR to https://www.github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy

As project Co-Lead, I wouldn't entertain this on my own time.

Comment: We have the same issue and we are willing to work on a PR. I´ll update here with our progress. @Noopur Srivastava let me know if you are interested on collaborating/testing.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue and are working on a PR to be submitted on GitHub this week.

We would appreciate feedback on it as soon as published.

We plan to:

- Add two properties: LogUserInfo and LogAppInfo (default to true)
- Use those to decide if we are going to append the current information

The logger output will be

```
    LogUserInfo=true and LogAppInfo=true: [EVENT SUCCESS Anonymus:null@unknown -> 
    /com.sample.package.ABC][msg]
    LogUserInfo=true and LogAppInfo=false: [EVENT SUCCESS Anonymus:null@unknown][msg]
    LogUserInfo=false and LogAppInfo=true: [EVENT SUCCESS /com.sample.package.ABC][msg]
    LogUserInfo=false and LogAppInfo=false: [EVENT SUCCESS][msg]
```

https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/issues/527
https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/pull/529

We understand this could be further improved with some string formatting templates and/or using MDC, but for now we will try to make the PR as simple as possible without messing with potential security problems or breaking functionality.